# Magento 2 not spawning consumer processes i DB (RabbitMQ)

Tags: magento2, database, cron, rabbit-mq, message-queue

I have setup Magento 2.4 with RabbitMQ. You can see my configuration here.

```
'queue' => [
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => 'rabbitmq.host',
        'port' => '53003',
        'user' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'virtualhost' => '/'
    ],
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1
],
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' => [
        'async.operations.all',
        'product_action_attribute.update',
        'product_action_attribute.website.update',
        'inventory.source.items.cleanup',
        'inventory.mass.update',
        'inventory.reservations.cleanup',
        'inventory.reservations.update',
        'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus',
        'inventory.indexer.sourceItem',
        'inventory.indexer.stock'
    ]
],
```

Magento 2 cron is running. You can see log here.

```
main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011739730834961,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2960,"realmem_start":176685056,"emalloc_start":162316640} [] []
```

Any bulk actions that are added into table `magneto_bulk` are never executed. All product bulks updated stays pending.
All entries in `queue_message_status` stays with status code 2 (pending)

This is my consumer list.

```
$ bin/magento queue:consumers:list
product_action_attribute.update
product_action_attribute.website.update
exportProcessor
inventory.source.items.cleanup
inventory.mass.update
inventory.reservations.cleanup
inventory.reservations.update
media.storage.catalog.image.resize
codegeneratorProcessor
inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus
inventory.indexer.sourceItem
inventory.indexer.stock
media.content.synchronization
media.gallery.synchronization
async.operations.all
```

Nothing happens when i try and run manuel with `$ bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update`

I see no errors in logs.
If i use default MySQL message queues, i am supposed to see some idle procceses in DB, correct? I do not see any processes at all.

Where should i start to debug this issue?

halp!

Comment: For refernece for others, I had a problem with a custom consumer not consuming from the queue with no errors showing/logging anywhere. After reading this thread, I ran bin/magento queue:consumers:start "my.custom.consumer.name" and this gave me an error in terminal that told me I had a script error. This error did not show anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The problem solved itself after i updated to 2.4.1. I am still not sure what was the problem though.

It seems kinda strange they need to make bulk updating products so complicated. Magento 2 are over-complicating many simple functions (in my opinion).

Comment: Yep I agree. I have no idea why so many extension specific config files are needed. For the record I have the same problem in 2.4.3 and it's just not clear why. I'm only using mysql for message queue. It should work seamlessly with minimal config!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if rabbitmq service is running:

- service rabbitmq-server status (centos)

Secondly look at the process

- ps aux | grep "async.operations.all"

if you have kill them(normally you should not have more than one)

- pkill -f 'async.operations.all'

and truncate magento_operation,magento_bulk and magento_acknowledged_bulk tables, flush cache - bin/magento c:f

It must works, let me know if it works